# UIPickerView Spin Confusion

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uipickerview

I have an app that I am currently making that has a PickerView and a UIButton. I want the user to tap the button and make the picker view show a random selection. I have been looking around and can't seem to come up with anything. I guess it would be similar to the Urbanspoon app. I know it is just a piece of a code but I can't think of what it could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [– selectRow:inComponent:animated:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html)

So do something like this:

```
[thePickerView selectRow:(arc4random() % numRows) inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```

where numRows is the number of rows.  If the rows are associated with an array names `rowArray` for instance it would be:

```
[thePickerView selectRow:(arc4random() % [rowArray count]) inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

So, upon pressing the button you would randomly choose an item from the data source of your PickerView and then call – selectRow:inComponent:animated: on your PickerView.